# Haworthia translucens is flowering (I Guess)

Tags: flowers, succulents

First i dont know the name of this succulent.So i just google "succulent translucent leaves" so i think it is Haworthia translucens. I bought this plant few month ago with two other haworthias, They were in smaller pot and later i moved them to slightly bigger pot and i water them once a month and now this Haworthia translucens  i think is flowering

So couple of questions

1. What will be the effect of this flower on mother plant.
2. Does this soon to be flower will hold some seeds? that i can use
   later

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is one of the many variations of Haworthia cymbiformis.   This species is very variable, based on where that form is found in the wild.   There are many pockets of this species that are cut off from one another, so they end up with the same species looking different from two different regions.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Agaves, Haworthias may flower many times, so if you want to keep them alive, just take care of your plant, and no need to remove the flowers.

Haworthias are normally pollinated by some [proboscis flies and bees](http://pza.sanbi.org/haworthiopsis). I don't know if bee species outside South-Africa recognize the flower as a pollen source, so you may need [hand-pollination](https://www.haworthia.com/pollination/). If you grow some Haworthias indoor, you may see for yourself if local insects can pollinate the flower or not. You have to try this to know. Normally, pollination success outside its habitat is very low. If you want to make seeds, I advise you to hand-pollinate them.

I have noticed that the related Gasteria, with its red and orange flowers, has a lot more pollination success rate. It may be due to the flower colors, attracting more pollinators and even sunbirds.

Comment: She only has one Haworthia blooming.  She would need another non-clone to pollinate the flowers of this  one.  I have found hand pollinating Haworthia very difficult.

Comment: Well today i say while misting my plants that there is another bloom coming.